# inter-process semaphores in Windows

Tags: windows, semaphore

is there any kind of semaphore for processes in Windows API? I found [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

but it is only for thread as I understood, thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the the help for CreateSemaphore() function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438(v=VS.85).aspx 
in the Remarks section, starting from "Multiple processes can handles....".

You'll find 3 cases there - all of them useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CreateSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CreateSemaphoreEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682446%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a named semaphore. You can use the name to access the semaphore from other locations by calling `CreateSemaphore` a second time.

Comment: Why not just CreateSemaphore? The Ex version is only available on Vista and up.